# How To Get Hierarchy With Linq C#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have stucked in a problem with linq c# there are three tables in my db
first is  `tbl_ActivitiesMaster (this contain Parent Child Data)`

```
CREATE TABLE  
tbl_ActivityMaster
(intActivityId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
strActivityDesc varchar(max) NULL,  
intActivityUOMId int,
dtDatetime datetime,
IsParentActivity int,
IsAlerternateActivity int NULL,
intParentToId int NULL,
intTaskId int NULL,
intAlternateId int NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_tbl_ActivityMaster PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (   
[intActivityId] ASC )
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS 
= ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Second is `tbl_TendersTaskActivities`

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_TendersTaskActivities(
    intID [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    intTaskId [int] NULL,
    intTenderId [int] NULL,
    intProjectWorkGroupId [int] NULL,
    intActivityId [int] NULL,
    ftActivityQty [float] NULL,
    ftActivityRate [float] NULL,
    intUomId int NULL,
    dtTaskStartDate [datetime] NULL,
    dtTaskCompletionDate [datetime] NULL,
    intFlag [int] NULL,
    IsCanceled [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_TendersTask] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [intID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want data From Table tbl_TendersTaskActivities with parent of actvities as hierarchy output
Please someone can resolve this problem 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing.  It's also _very_ not clear what you've tried so far.  Can you show an example of the code you're using that _isn't_ working and explain how it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
from m in DataContext.tbl_ActivityMaster
             join d in DataContext.tbl_TendersTaskActivities on m.intActivityId equals d.intActivityId    into temp
             from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
             group SysDocument by m
```

Answer (score 0):

In LinqToSql you'd use `DataLoadOptions` to pull in related records:

```
DataLoadOptions myOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
myOptions.LoadWith<ActivityMaster>(x => x.TendersTaskActivities);

using (CustomDataContext myDC = new CustomDataContext(connStr))
{
  myDC.LoadOptions = myOptions;

  List<ActivityMaster> masters = myDC.ActivityMasters
    .Where(filter)
    .ToList();  //TendersTaskActivities also loaded.
  return masters; 
}
```